# how can I send emails from react using sendinblue?

Tags: reactjs, email, html-email, sendinblue

I am working in React applications (using the .net core in the back-end)
I have to send emails from the client side , we have to use **sendinblue** instead of mailgun , I need your help

Answer (score 4):

You **should not** send emails from the client side.
Consider that in doing so, you're going to expose your API Key to any client, leading to a severe vulnerability for your application (anyone could impersonate you and send emails as if they were you).

In order to really make that work, you should perform an AJAX request to **your server** and there, connect to the Sendinblue API and make the request to send the email. In this case, the API Key could be safely stored in your server.